# Python exception handling: Check return value of function

Tags: python, exception

Before using the value of a return of a function, I want to check if the value is useable. So what I have is more or less the following:

```
def get_module():
  import foo
  return foo

def do_something():
  try:
    module = get_module()
  except:
    print "error"

  module.bar()
```

Unfortunately, it seems to me that this never raises an exception. In particular, I want to check (a) that the module was transferred correctly and (b) that the module is one of three possible modules.

I know I can check through if-statements, but I feel that exception handing is ought to be the correct way.

Comment: it never raises an exception... if `foo` doesn't exist.  Otherwise `get_module` will raise `ImportError` (which you should catch explicitly instead of a bare `except`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foo` cannot be imported, the code below will produce an [ImportError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError) exception:

```
def get_module():
    import foo
    return foo


def do_something():
    try:
        module = get_module()
    except ImportError:
        print "Import Error!"
        raise

    module.bar()


do_something()
```

Produces:

```
Import Error! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
import foo 
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Note, that you should either reraise the exception via `raise` in the `except` block, or make a `return`, so that you don't get an error on `module.bar()` line because of undefined `module` variable.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah yes. I think I start to get Python's exception handling. Thank you!